# JQuery most effective way to move a object?

Tags: jquery, html, performance

Well im moving a object from a to b with the following

```
dotItem.css('left', '0%').show(0).animate({ left: '100%' }, 2000, 'speedInOut', .....
```

this seems to render sluggish in Opera is there any better way to move a object from the left to the right side of the parent object?

Here is the example code http://jsfiddle.net/64j6v/

Look in the function moveDot thats where the actual movement takes place.

Comment: don't worry about it. practically no one uses opera.

Comment: css3 yay http://jsfiddle.net/64j6v/2/ but opera doesnt support keyframes arg.

Comment: @Jason i use opera :P so it kind of matters to me at least...

Comment: @Jason some projects require multiple browser support and developing for Opera is necessary.

Comment: @xCRKxTyPHooN yes i am aware. it was said tongue-in-cheek

Comment: Works fine here, no hesitation. Opera 11.61 under Win 7 Starter, on Acer AspireOne D255, 1.66 GHz.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot could you try this http://jsfiddle.net/64j6v/embedded/result/

Comment: @Petoj Fiddle is intermittently jerky in Opera and similar, maybe slightly worse, in IE9. As with all js animations it is subject to interruption by other activity on the computer (eg. background processes). For some users it will be smoother than for others.